# How to put several strings into a list in a for loop?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm using a for loop to search a list of protein IDs in NCBI protein database, and try to convert these IDs into the description. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import SeqIO

df2=pd.read_csv('ID.txt', header=None)
df.columns = ['protein_ID']  # put a header 'protein_ID' to the dataframe
lists=df.protein_ID.tolist() #convert the column into a list of protein IDs.

description = ''
for num, line in enumerate(lists):
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="protein", id=line, rettype="gb", retmode="text")
    record = SeqIO.read(handle, "genbank")
    description += record.description

description
```

It returns one huge string:

```
'hypothetical protein UR61_C0009G0014 [candidate division WS6 bacterium GW2011_GWE1_34_7]ATPase [candidate division WS6 bacterium GW2011_GWE2_33_157]hypothetical protein UR96_C0034G0007 [candidate division WS6 bacterium GW2011_GWC1_36_11]phosphoenolpyruvate synthase [Candidatus Komeilibacteria bacterium RIFOXYC1_FULL_37_11]'
```

What I want is a list of strings with new line breaks, like this:

```
[
'hypothetical protein UR61_C0009G0014 [candidate division WS6 bacterium GW2011_GWE1_34_7]',
'ATPase [candidate division WS6 bacterium GW2011_GWE2_33_157]',
'hypothetical protein UR96_C0034G0007 [candidate division WS6 bacterium GW2011_GWC1_36_11]',
'phosphoenolpyruvate synthase [Candidatus Komeilibacteria bacterium RIFOXYC1_FULL_37_11]'
]
```

How to achieve this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Make `description` a list - `description = []` - and do `description.append(record.description)`.

Comment: Oh yes, Thank you, That easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want is a list of strings

```
description = []
for num, line in enumerate(lists):
    ....
    description.append(record.description)
```

> with new line breaks

By default, lists are not printed this way, use [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)

```
import pprint

# you original code here

pprint.pprint(description)
```